# node.js code is not executing without prompting any error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run the following Node.js code through command prompt. But, the code does not execute ( It is not showing any error on the command prompt).
I have installed necessary `pubnub` package using (`npm install pubnub`) as well. But, still the problem remains same.

Am I missing something? The code link is here https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk#initializing-the-client

```
var PubNub = require('pubnub')

function publish() {

    pubnub = new PubNub({
        publishKey : 'demo',
        subscribeKey : 'demo'
    })

    function publishSampleMessage() {
        console.log("Since we're publishing on subscribe connectEvent, we're sure we'll receive the following publish.");
        var publishConfig = {
            channel : "hello_world",
            message : "Hello from PubNub Docs!"
        }
        pubnub.publish(publishConfig, function(status, response) {
            console.log(status, response);
        })
    }

    pubnub.addListener({
        status: function(statusEvent) {
            if (statusEvent.category === "PNConnectedCategory") {
                publishSampleMessage();
            }
        },
        message: function(message) {
            console.log("New Message!!", message);
        },
        presence: function(presenceEvent) {
            // handle presence
        }
    })      
    console.log("Subscribing..");
    pubnub.subscribe({
        channels: ['hello_world'] 
    });
};
```

Comment: you create a `function publish`, but have call it at end so it's will be run ?

Comment: Thank you so much, Dkouk!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the function publish() but you forgot to execute it. You just have to add `publish();` at the end of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much!!